# STOP the <a and href tags pops up to another page and instead play within the main page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm kind of new to the programming world and the professor requires me to stop the popping and play the music in the background of the main page when he clicks on the word **"PLAY MUSIC"**. I don't know how to do that, although I have tried a lot. Is it even possible to do that ?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  for (var i=1; i <= $('.slider__slide').length; i++){
    $('.slider__indicators').append('<div class="slider__indicator" data-slide="'+i+'"></div>')
  }
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.slider__wrap').addClass('slider__wrap--hacked');
  }, 1000);
})

function goToSlide(number){
  $('.slider__slide').removeClass('slider__slide--active');
  $('.slider__slide[data-slide='+number+']').addClass('slider__slide--active');
}

$('.slider__next, .go-to-next').on('click', function(){
  var currentSlide = Number($('.slider__slide--active').data('slide'));
  var totalSlides = $('.slider__slide').length;
  currentSlide++
  if (currentSlide > totalSlides){
    currentSlide = 1;
  }
  goToSlide(currentSlide);
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #aaa;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #777;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slider__wrap {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  transform: translateX(100vw);
  top: 0%;
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: transform 450ms cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86);
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  transition-delay: 450ms;
  opacity: 0;
}
.slider__wrap--hacked {
  opacity: 1;
}
.slider__back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: none;
  transition: filter 450ms cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86);
}
.slider__inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0%;
  background-size: auto 133.3333%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: none;
  transform: scale(0.75);
  transition: transform 450ms cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86), box-shadow 450ms cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86), opacity 450ms step-end;
  opacity: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 3vh 3vh rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  padding: 15vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.slider__content {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: white;
  font-family: "Heebo", sans-serif;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 450ms;
}
.slider__content h1 {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 9vh;
  line-height: 0.85;
  margin-bottom: 0.75vh;
  pointer-events: none;
  text-shadow: 0 0.375vh 0.75vh rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.slider__content a {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 2.4vh;
  letter-spacing: 0.3vh;
  font-weight: 100;
  position: relative;
}
.slider__content a:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 9vh;
  background: white;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 6vh;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  transition: transform 900ms cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86);
}
.slider__content a:before {
  content: "";
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  display: block;
  width: 1vh;
  height: 1vh;
  transform: translateX(0) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Heebo", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  top: 50%;
  left: 15vh;
  transition: transform 900ms cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86);
}
.slider__content a:hover:after {
  transform: scaleX(1.5);
  transition: transform 1200ms cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86);
}
.slider__content a:hover:before {
  transform: translateX(6vh) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  transition: transform 1200ms cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86);
}
.slider__slide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  transition: transform 600ms cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86);
  transition-delay: 600ms;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 0;
}
.slider__slide--active {
  transform: translatex(0%);
  z-index: 2;
}
.slider__slide--active .slider__wrap {
  transform: translateX(0);
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation: none;
          animation: none;
}
.slider__slide--active .slider__back {
  filter: blur(1.5vh);
  transition: filter 900ms cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86);
  transition-delay: 900ms !important;
}
.slider__slide--active .slider__inner {
  transform: scale(0.8);
  box-shadow: 0 1vh 6vh rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  pointer-events: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: transform 900ms cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86), box-shadow 900ms cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86), opacity 1ms step-end;
  transition-delay: 900ms;
}
.slider__slide--active .slider__content {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 1350ms;
}
.slider__slide:not(.slider__slide--active) .slider__wrap {
  -webkit-animation-name: hack;
          animation-name: hack;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 900ms;
          animation-duration: 900ms;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 450ms;
          animation-delay: 450ms;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86);
          animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86);
}
@-webkit-keyframes hack {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-100vw);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  51% {
    transform: translateX(-100vw);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  52% {
    transform: translateX(100vw);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100vw);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes hack {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-100vw);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  51% {
    transform: translateX(-100vw);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  52% {
    transform: translateX(100vw);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100vw);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.slider__slide:nth-child(1) .slider__back, .slider__slide:nth-child(1) .slider__inner {
  background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1600/800/?image=931);
}
.slider__slide:nth-child(2) .slider__back, .slider__slide:nth-child(2) .slider__inner {
  background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1600/800/?image=929);
}
.slider__slide:nth-child(3) .slider__back, .slider__slide:nth-child(3) .slider__inner {
  background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1600/800/?image=927);
}

.sig {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Popout Slider</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Heebo:100,900|Open+Sans:300" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider__slide slider__slide--active" data-slide="1">
    <div class="slider__wrap">
      <div class="slider__back"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__inner">
      <div class="slider__content">
        <h1>Slide <br> One</h1><a class="go-to-next">next</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider__slide" data-slide="2">
    <div class="slider__wrap">
      <div class="slider__back"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__inner">
      <div class="slider__content">
        <h1>Slide <br> Two</h1><a class="go-to-next">next</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider__slide" data-slide="3">
    <div class="slider__wrap">
      <div class="slider__back"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__inner">
      <div class="slider__content">
        <h1>Slide <br> Three</h1><a class="go-to-next">next</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider__indicators"></div>
</div><a class="sig" href="https://audio.code.org/win1.mp3" target="_blank">PLAY MUSIC</a>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: remove `target="_blank"`.

Comment: Use an <audio> tag.

Comment: @MahmouDSkafi I did try and it didn't work

Comment: @CherryDT I did use but it won't work either.

Comment: "it didn't work" isn't useful. You need to show exactly what you did and in what way it failed.

Comment: I am so sorry, I was really hurry rushing to school at that time so I kinda answered quickly. Here is what happened, when I add the <audio> tag only without any Javascript, it still pops out the main page window to another separate pages. I figured it out that I need to use Vanilla Javascript to fix the problem. Once again, I am so sorry for the rush comment. Have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow these steps:

1. Add an `<audio>` tag to your HTML with a `src` attribute containing the URI for the audio you want to play. This tag is the one which will load the content from `https://audio.code.org/win1.mp3`.

   ```
   <audio src="https://audio.code.org/win1.mp3" id="myAudio"></audio>
   ```
2. Remove the `href` attribute from your `.sig` anchor (`<a>`) element, since it will not take the user to the audio resource webpage anymore. Instead, it will work like a button which will be responsible for playing the audio when clicked.

   Having an `<a>` element working as a `<button>` element isn't good for accessibility, unless you make this behavior explicit by means of `role="button"`. This attribute will indicate that your `<a>` will work as a button. Yes, you can also replace that tag with a `<button>` tag as long as you are willing to modify your CSS for maintaining aesthetics.

   ```
   <a class="sig" role="button">PLAY MUSIC</a>
   ```
3. In your JavaScript code, attach a click event to `.sig`, telling it to play the audio you want when it's clicked.

   ```
   $('.sig').on('click', () => $('#myAudio').get(0).play());
   ```

Try it below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  for (var i=1; i <= $('.slider__slide').length; i++){
    $('.slider__indicators').append('<div class="slider__indicator" data-slide="'+i+'"></div>')
  }
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.slider__wrap').addClass('slider__wrap--hacked');
  }, 1000);
})

function goToSlide(number){
  $('.slider__slide').removeClass('slider__slide--active');
  $('.slider__slide[data-slide='+number+']').addClass('slider__slide--active');
}

$('.slider__next, .go-to-next').on('click', function(){
  var currentSlide = Number($('.slider__slide--active').data('slide'));
  var totalSlides = $('.slider__slide').length;
  currentSlide++
  if (currentSlide > totalSlides){
    currentSlide = 1;
  }
  goToSlide(currentSlide);
})

  $('.sig').on('click', () => $('#myAudio').get(0).play());
```

```css
body {
  background: #aaa;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #777;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slider__wrap {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  transform: translateX(100vw);
  top: 0%;
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: transform 450ms cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86);
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  transition-delay: 450ms;
  opacity: 0;
}
.slider__wrap--hacked {
  opacity: 1;
}
.slider__back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: none;
  transition: filter 450ms cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86);
}
.slider__inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0%;
  background-size: auto 133.3333%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: none;
  transform: scale(0.75);
  transition: transform 450ms cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86), box-shadow 450ms cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86), opacity 450ms step-end;
  opacity: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 3vh 3vh rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  padding: 15vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.slider__content {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: white;
  font-family: "Heebo", sans-serif;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 450ms;
}
.slider__content h1 {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 9vh;
  line-height: 0.85;
  margin-bottom: 0.75vh;
  pointer-events: none;
  text-shadow: 0 0.375vh 0.75vh rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.slider__content a {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 2.4vh;
  letter-spacing: 0.3vh;
  font-weight: 100;
  position: relative;
}
.slider__content a:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 9vh;
  background: white;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 6vh;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  transition: transform 900ms cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86);
}
.slider__content a:before {
  content: "";
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  display: block;
  width: 1vh;
  height: 1vh;
  transform: translateX(0) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Heebo", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  top: 50%;
  left: 15vh;
  transition: transform 900ms cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86);
}
.slider__content a:hover:after {
  transform: scaleX(1.5);
  transition: transform 1200ms cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86);
}
.slider__content a:hover:before {
  transform: translateX(6vh) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  transition: transform 1200ms cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86);
}
.slider__slide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  transition: transform 600ms cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86);
  transition-delay: 600ms;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 0;
}
.slider__slide--active {
  transform: translatex(0%);
  z-index: 2;
}
.slider__slide--active .slider__wrap {
  transform: translateX(0);
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation: none;
          animation: none;
}
.slider__slide--active .slider__back {
  filter: blur(1.5vh);
  transition: filter 900ms cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86);
  transition-delay: 900ms !important;
}
.slider__slide--active .slider__inner {
  transform: scale(0.8);
  box-shadow: 0 1vh 6vh rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  pointer-events: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: transform 900ms cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86), box-shadow 900ms cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86), opacity 1ms step-end;
  transition-delay: 900ms;
}
.slider__slide--active .slider__content {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 1350ms;
}
.slider__slide:not(.slider__slide--active) .slider__wrap {
  -webkit-animation-name: hack;
          animation-name: hack;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 900ms;
          animation-duration: 900ms;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 450ms;
          animation-delay: 450ms;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86);
          animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86);
}
@-webkit-keyframes hack {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-100vw);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  51% {
    transform: translateX(-100vw);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  52% {
    transform: translateX(100vw);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100vw);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes hack {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-100vw);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  51% {
    transform: translateX(-100vw);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  52% {
    transform: translateX(100vw);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100vw);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.slider__slide:nth-child(1) .slider__back, .slider__slide:nth-child(1) .slider__inner {
  background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1600/800/?image=931);
}
.slider__slide:nth-child(2) .slider__back, .slider__slide:nth-child(2) .slider__inner {
  background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1600/800/?image=929);
}
.slider__slide:nth-child(3) .slider__back, .slider__slide:nth-child(3) .slider__inner {
  background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1600/800/?image=927);
}

.sig {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  z-index: 9999;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Popout Slider</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Heebo:100,900|Open+Sans:300" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider__slide slider__slide--active" data-slide="1">
    <div class="slider__wrap">
      <div class="slider__back"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__inner">
      <div class="slider__content">
        <h1>Slide <br> One</h1><a class="go-to-next">next</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider__slide" data-slide="2">
    <div class="slider__wrap">
      <div class="slider__back"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__inner">
      <div class="slider__content">
        <h1>Slide <br> Two</h1><a class="go-to-next">next</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider__slide" data-slide="3">
    <div class="slider__wrap">
      <div class="slider__back"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__inner">
      <div class="slider__content">
        <h1>Slide <br> Three</h1><a class="go-to-next">next</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider__indicators"></div>
</div>
<audio src="https://audio.code.org/win1.mp3" id="myAudio"></audio>
<a class="sig" role="button">PLAY MUSIC</a>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow, it works !!!. May I ask how to pause it please ? Thank you so much.

Comment: Oh, I figured it out how to pause it by using onClick="togglePlay() and vanilla javascript. Thank you so much for your help